# QT 5.x compilation of Windows software on Linux

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to compile windows software on linux with qt but each time I try to compile I get the following error:

```
i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I. -I/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include -I/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtSvg -I/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtWidgets -I/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtGui -I/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtNetwork -I/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/include/QtCore -Irelease -I. -I/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o release/inventoryview.o View/inventoryview.cpp
```

> In file included from View/inventoryview.cpp:2:0:
>       ./ui_inventoryview.h:21:50: fatal error:  Widget\Inventory\inventoryplusbutton.h: No such file or directory
>       compilation terminated.
>       Makefile.Release:6009: recipe for target 'release/inventoryview.o' failed
>       make[1]: Leaving directory '/builds/Skytwoo/qt-test/Synaps-Software'
>       make[1]: *** [release/inventoryview.o] Error 1
>
>       Makefile:36: recipe for target 'release' failed
>
>       make: *** [release] Error 2

I check multiple times and every folder exists.

Everything is run on Ubuntu inside a docker container with this command.

```
make -f Makefile.Release
```

Comment: Note the **back**slashes in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [BoBTFish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171191/bobtfish) said, you can't have \ (backslashes) in your path. What you have to do here is to change `Widget\Inventory\inventoryplusbutton.h` into `Widget/Inventory/inventoryplusbutton.h` and make sure it exists.